# $\lim_{y\downarrow 0} yE(1/X ; X>y)=0$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, expectation

> Let $X>0$ but do ***NOT*** assume $E(1/X)< \infty$. Show that
>   $$\lim_{y\downarrow 0} yE(1/X ; X>y)=0$$.

I tried to use Jensen Inequality but this is not working.

There was another problem which was
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} yE(1/X ; X>y)=0$$

It was easy since $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} yE(1/X ; X>y)< \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} P(X>y)=0$. But this trick not working on the above problem.

Need Help!!

Comment: Why does the approach for the other problem not work here? $\operatorname{E}\left(\frac1X\,\middle|\,X\gt y\right)\le\frac1y$ is it not?

Comment: @robjohn but $y\to0$, now.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the wrong limit.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For any $\epsilon\gt0$,
$$
\begin{align}
y\operatorname{E}\left(\frac1X\,\middle|\,X\gt y\right)
&=\int_{x\gt y}\frac yx\,\mathrm{d}\!\operatorname{P}(X\le x)\\
&=\int_{x\gt y}\frac yx\,\mathrm{d}\!\operatorname{P}(X\le x\land X\le\epsilon)\\
&+\int_{x\gt y}\frac yx\,\mathrm{d}\!\operatorname{P}(X\le x\land X\gt\epsilon)\\[3pt]
&\le\operatorname{P}(y\lt X\le\epsilon)+\frac y\epsilon
\end{align}
$$
**Note:** this fails if $\operatorname{P}(X=0)\gt0$, however the assumption $X\gt0$ implies $\operatorname{P}(X=0)=0$.